# How is it possible to run functions in unnamed classes (if possible multiple?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm quite new to Python 3 and recently started programming with the tk toolkit in the form of tkinter. I started programming two classes for my Space Invaders Remix, but I came across some problems. Most commonly, I had to create multiple variables for classes for the bullets, but then I couldn't update all of them, as they were all unnamed. Here's my code, if it helps:

```
from tkinter import *
import easygui
import random
import time
from pygame import mixer



tk = Tk()
tk.title('Space Invaders')
tk.resizable(600,400)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width = 550, height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness = 0)
canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,600,400,fill ='black')
position = 0

class Spaceship:
    def __init__(self, canvas, colour):

        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,30,20, fill=colour)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def update(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, canvas, colour):
        self.paddle = Spaceship
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 10,20,fill=colour)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, position, 100)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -1
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()

    def update(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -1)





spaceship = Spaceship(canvas, 'white')



def add_bullet(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        Bullet(canvas,'white')


while 1:
    canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', add_bullet)
    spaceship.update()
    Bullet.update()

    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Again, I'm quite new to Python, and there's probably a simple answer.

By the way,I've imported

Comment: You can use a list of bullet objects created as a stack in order to handle the bullets that exists in a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep bullets on the list

```
all_bullets = []

bullet = Bullet(canvas,'white')

all_bullets.append( bullet )
```

and then you can use it.

```
for x in all_bullets:
     x.update()
```

If  you need only one bullet than use as always

```
bullet = Bullet(canvas,'white')

bullet.update()
```

---

BTW:

You don't have to bind key in `while` all over again - do it once before `while`.

Don't use endless loop `while 1` and `time.sleep` because tkinter can't execute all own functions. Use `after(time, function name)`.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you use **after**? Now the game is finished, but I'm looking for ways to speed it up.